# Error on removing fields added dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add 3 fields dynamically (2 text fields and 1 remove button). The add button is working fine. The problem is the remove function. It's only removing the remove button, but not the other 2 fields it should.

This is my html code:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">

    <div class="field_wrapper form-group col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" name="id[]" value="" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" name="name[]" value="" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button btn btn-primary" title="Add field">Adicionar Valor</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

This is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var maxField = 10; //Input fields increment limitation
    var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
    var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
    //var fieldHTML = '<div><input type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button btn btn-danger2" title="Remove field">Remover</a></div>'; //New input field html 
    var fieldHTML = '<div class="field_wrapper form-group col-sm-12"><div class="form-group col-sm-4"><input type="text" name="id[]" value="" class="form-control"/></div><div class="form-group col-sm-4"><input type="text" name="name[]" value="" class="form-control"/></div><div class="form-group col-sm-4"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button btn btn-primary" title="Add field">Remover</a></div></div>'; //New input field html 
    var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
    $(addButton).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
        if(x < maxField){ //Check maximum number of input fields
            x++; //Increment field counter
            $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); // Add field html
        }
    });
    $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){ //Once remove button is clicked
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
        x--; //Decrement field counter
    });
});
</script>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Use `$(this).closest('.field_wrapper').remove();` inside the remove click callback. The remove button is nested in `div` and `parent()` will only get the direct ascendant element so, it only removes the parent `div` element and not the whole markup.

Comment: look at what the parent div has in it....just that button. So then go to jquery api....look for other traversal methods ...would find things like `parents()` and `closest()` and there are examples for all methods there

Comment: before asking question. use browser developer tools to check whether specified element matches or not. then use remove, hide, show etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're removing the `$(this).parent('div')`, that is giving you the form-group of the button and not the intended `.field_wrapper`, what you can do instead is use the `.closest('.field_wrapper')` which will find the element you've added.

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lucaslazaro/1e5b2bpt/), for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Just changed:

```
$(this).parent('div').remove();
```

for:

```
$(this).closest('.field_wrapper').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 $(this).parent('div').parent('div').remove()
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shree/4973odzq/)